# I don't understand this Perl Syntax, has anyone got any idea?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, perl-data-structures

I have got this part from a Perl plugin. I don't understand what it does. Is it an array of associative arrays? If so, then shouldn't it be started with @? Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
my $arguments =
  [ { 'name' => "process_exp",
    'desc' => "{BasePlugin.process_exp}",
    'type' => "regexp",
    'deft' => &get_default_process_exp(),
    'reqd' => "no" },
  { 'name' => "assoc_images",
    'desc' => "{MP4Plugin.assoc_images}",
    'type' => "flag",
    'deft' => "",
    'reqd' => "no" },
  { 'name' => "applet_metadata",
    'desc' => "{MP4Plugin.applet_metadata}",
    'type' => "flag",
    'deft' => "" },
  { 'name' => "metadata_fields",
    'desc' => "{MP4Plugin.metadata_fields}",
    'type' => "string",
    'deft' => "Title,Artist,Genre" },
  { 'name' => "file_rename_method",
    'desc' => "{BasePlugin.file_rename_method}",
    'type' => "enum",
    'deft' => &get_default_file_rename_method(), # by default rename imported files and assoc files using this encoding
    'list' => $BasePlugin::file_rename_method_list,
    'reqd' => "no"
  } ];
```

Comment: it's a reference to an array of hash references

Comment: "hash references" is just the basic Perl structure, I see that and think that it is an array of *records* with *named fields*. They might even be blessed into a class at some point `bless( $_, 'SomeClass' ) foreach @$arguments`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bwmat said it's a reference to an Array of Hash references. Read

```
$ man perlref
```

or

```
$ man perlreftut     # this is a bit more straightforward
```

for if you want to know more about references.

By the way in fiew words in Perl you can do:

```
@array = ( 1, 2 );          # declare an array
$array_reference = \@array; # take the reference to that array
$array_reference->[0] = 2;  # overwrite 1st position of @array

$numbers = [ 3, 4 ];        # this is another valid array ref declaration. Note [ ] instead of ( )
```

the same thing happens with hashes.

By the way in fiew words in Perl you can do:

```
%hash = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );
$hash_reference = \%hash; 
$hash_reference->{foo} = 2;

$langs = { perl => 'cool', php => 'ugly' }; # this is another valid hash ref declaration. Note { } instead of ( )
```

And... yes, you can dereference these references.

```
%{ $hash_reference }
```

will be treated as it was a hash, so if you want to print the keys of `$langs` above, you can do:

```
print $_, "\n" foreach ( keys %{ $langs } );
```

To dereference an array ref use `@{ }` instead of `%{ }`. Even `sub` can be dereferenced.

```
sub foo
{
  print "hello world\n";
}

my %hash = ( call => \&foo );

&{ $hash{call} }; # this allows you to call the sub foo
```

Answer (score 1):

`$arguments` is an array reference (a reference/pointer to an array)

You initialize arrays with `()` and array references with `[]`

```
my @array = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my $array_ref = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

You can create a reference with `\`

```
my $other_array_ref = \@array;
```

When you use an array reference you will then to dereference it when using:

```
for my $element ( @{$array_ref} )
```

or

```
print ${$array_ref}[0];
```

See `man perlref`

Back to your question: `$arguments` is a reference to an array of hash references (initialized with `{}`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [hash of hashes](http://p3rl.org/dsc#HASHES-OF-HASHES) reference.

you may need to dereference like

`%newhash = %{$arguments}`

and print the data as

`print $newhash{'name'}`

Comment: `Can't coerce array into hash` with strict and warnings.

Comment: An array of hash references, surely? Or, more accurately, a reference to an array of hash references.